# Excel Product Categorization in Python

Tags: python, excel, machine-learning, data-science, data-analysis

I'm trying to break up Product names into categories, for example if the product is "Demi Baguette", the category should be "Baguette" and sub category "Demi". I have looked at NLP articles but nothing seems to be what I need as they all focus on sentences and text.
I've seen other questions answered by saying to use a dict, however there is over 15 thousand rows in the excel file so that's not really possible.

Any ideas as to how I can tackle this or where I can look?

Here is an example of my data.

[image]

So I would want the category to be "Soup" and then sub categories based on flavour e.g"Chicken", and misc labels "Cream".